# playOrm - debug/run - TestManyToOne.java w/ breakpoint @ line79

Tags: java, eclipse, playorm

As suggested, drilling down into the test case, TestManyToOne.java and running/debuging readWriteBasic(NoSqlEntityManager)

I get 1 error.
 
readWriteBasic - (Method not found) 
*and* 
     Unrooted Tests
          initializationError

My concern here is that i do not get the option to step into.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ran into an annoying eclipse bug.  Try this

1. Put cursor somewhere else in the file(not on a test method) and right click and Run As -> Junit test.  Does this work?  It should.
2. Now put cursor on test method and then right click on test method and Run As -> Junit test.  This should now work.
3. Now do the same as #2 except choose Debug As -> Junit test

If #1 fails, then right click the project, choose refresh, then click Project -> Clean... and then try all 3 steps again.